# Tengo problemas para ingresar a mi vps

Tags: ssh, vps, conexión

Estaba configurando mi vps y durante la noche se bloqueó mi acceso. No puedo entrar al panel de control ni por ssh.
Se que es un problema de mi red ya que si entro desde otro lado puedo hacerlo.
Cuando lo intento desde mi computadora me sale lo siguiente en el ssh:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el navegador cuando intento acceder al panel de control sale que la conexión ha caducado. Sin embargo si escaneo el puerto de la conexión al panel de control me figura como abierto. El del ssh no y no se como abrirlo ya que uso el cortafuegos de avast y en google no aparece nada, por otro lado ya intente desactivar el cortafuegos y sigue sin pasar nada.
Desde ya les agradezco a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: creo que debes intentar reiniciar la pagina.

Comment: ¿el vps tiene algun firewall?  Tiene pinta que te ha baneado la IP casera que tengas y si dices que puedes entrar por otro lado vete al firewall de tu VPS y mira si estas bloqueado

Comment: El firewall no es ya que aparte de agregar mi ip a la lista blanca llegue a reinstalar el SO sin siquiera un CP y sigo igual

Comment: Pues haz un traceroute (o tracert segun el SO) desde tu IP hasta el servidor y viceversa para ver en que salto se para, para tener un poco más claro el diagnostico de donde puede estar el tapon

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, gracias masterguru, hice un tracerouter y resultó que mi router había baneado la dirección, por eso entraba desde otra red y no desde la mía.
Muchísimas gracias a todos por tomarse el trabajo de responderme.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Saludos